# Fortran: gfortran gives error "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"

Tags: compiling, fortran

I am trying a simple command `gfortran --version` and I get this error:

```
marcus@aurelius:~$ gfortran -v
-bash: /usr/local/bin/gfortran: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I seem to get the same error no matter what I try to compile with `gfortran`. How can I fix this?

This is what is installed in `/usr/bin`:

```
$ ls /usr/bin/ | grep gfortran
gfortran
gfortran-4.8
x86_64-linux-gnu-gfortran
x86_64-linux-gnu-gfortran-4.8
```

and this is what is installed in `/usr/local/bin`;

```
$ ls /usr/local/bin/
f2py          isympy        theano-nose
gfortran      miranda       theano-test
gfortran-4.8  theano-cache  x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0-gfortran
```

Comment: How did you install `gfortran`? When installed from the repositories, it would normally go in `/usr/bin` rather than `/usr/local/bin` - it sounds like you manually installed a wrong version for your system into `/usr/local`

Comment: @steeldriver I just updated my question to show what is in the directories that you pointed out. Should I delete the `gfortran` package using `apt-get remove --purge` and then reinstall? How do i find out the right way to install in my case?

Comment: @steeldriver I don't know how it was installed, I just tried to install a package that uses fortran, and then I found out it wasn't working.

Comment: So... reading between the lines, you unpacked / installed `x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0-gfortran` into `/usr/local` at some point, and since `/usr/local/bin` is before `/usr/bin` in your `PATH`, that's the one that the system tries to execute. Have you checked that `/usr/bin/gfortran --version` works?

Comment: @steeldriver no `/usr/bin/gfortran --version` doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn't work" meaning what, exactly? same error or different?

Comment: @steeldriver Actually, sorry, it does work

Comment: So - you have a number of options depending on exactly what you are using gfortran *for* - from defining an alias, setting a temporary `PATH`, setting an appropriate shell variable such as `FC=/usr/bin/gfortran` before calling `make` to moving/renaming/deleting the "bad" /usr/local/gfortran (don't resort to that unless you are sure it's not required).

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks a lot, I just deleted the gfortran binaries in /usr/local/bin, uninstalled and reinstalled gfortran and it works